# SQL How to convert a decimal to a string

Tags: sql, oracle

In a SELECT statement I want to convert values to strings ie. SELECT TO_STRING(value).

How can I do this in Oracle SQL?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use either the [`TO_CHAR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions201.htm#SQLRF06130) or the [`CAST`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions023.htm#SQLRF00613) function:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(123.45) FROM DUAL

SELECT CAST(123.45 AS VARCHAR2(10)) FROM DUAL
```

Comment: If you want a particular format mask, TO_CHAR is appropriate [eg TO_CHAR(1234.5,'999,990.00') ]

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CAST(column_name as data_type) from ...
```

might work

HTH